# Reading unicode text in Java and display on JLabel?

Tags: java, unicode, io

I have the following code reading a file containing unicode text (Japanese).

```
File f = new File("f.txt"); // the file was saved with utf-8 encoding
FileReader fr = new FileReader(f);
BufferedReader br = new BufferedReader(fr);

s = br.readLine();
lblData.setText(s); // JLabel lblData was set font as Tahoma

br.close();
fr.close();
```

Im using window 7 and the system already installed Japanese font (MSMINCHO.TTF).

If I run the above code in Netbeans (6.9) editor then the program display correctly.

But when I exported to jar file and run the program independently of Netbeans, then it is no longer displaying correctly.

I dont know why this happened and how to fix it?

Comment: why don't you use explicit localization to avoid dependencies like that?

Comment: [Java localization.](http://www.progdoc.de/papers/intSwing/intswing/intswing.html)

Comment: Try setting the default encoding explicitly. This might be useful: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/361975/setting-the-default-java-character-encoding

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use FileInputStream and initialise the reader like this:

```
br = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(new FileInputStream(filename), Charset.forName("UTF-8")));
```

that will give you the characters correct from the file.